# Shell Command for lines that have decimal number in parenthesis & upper/lower case letters

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have to write a one line shell command that will count all lines beginning with a decimal number in parenthesis, with a mix of both upper and lower case letters, and end with a period.

I'm very confused. I tried some but I cannot get the parenthesis and ending with period part.

Comment: an example with expected output would be better.

Comment: duplicate?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35715258/awk-i-need-to-write-a-one-line-shell-command-that-will-count-all-lines-that?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the parentheses depend on which regex dialect you use.

```
grep -c '^([0-9]*) [A-Za-z]*\.$' file
```

uses literal parentheses, while

```
grep -Ec '^\([0-9]+\) [A-Za-z]+\.$' file
```

needs backslashes.  Note also the use of single quotes to prevent the shell from intervening with the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This may do:

```
cat file
Here are my data
Some number (12.3)
Even more
And more
And end here.
This does not count
```

```
awk '/\([0-9)+\.[0-9]+\)/ {f=1} f {a++} /[^0-9]\.[^0-9]*/ {f=0} END {print a}' file
4
```

This start counting when number is found in form of `(<digit>.<digit>)`
And ends with a period `.` with no digit in front `[^0-9]\.[^0-9]*`