# AWK - I need to write a one line shell command that will count all lines that

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I need to write this solution as an AWK command. I am stuck on the last question:

---

*Write a one line shell command that will count all lines in a file called "file.txt" that begin with a decimal number in parenthesis, containing a mix of both upper and lower case letters, and end with a period.*

Example(s):

> **This is the format of lines we want to print. Lines that do not match this format should be skipped:**
>
> (10) This is a sample line from file.txt that your script should
>   count.
>
> (117) And this is another line your script should count.
>
> **Lines like this, as well as other non-matching lines, should be skipped:**
>
> 15 this line should not be printed
>
> and this line should not be printed
>
> ---

Thanks in advance, I'm not really sure how to tackle this in one line.

Comment: The problem statement is ambiguous.  Must the line contain only upper and lower case characters?  If so, neither of the samples given that match should match, since they also contain whitespace.  Must there be anything after the number in parentheses?  Can there be any characters after the closing parenthese other than upper and lower case letters (and apparently whitespace)?  Can there be alphabetic characters inside the parentheses?  Decide, specify the decisions you've made, write a regex that matches, and be done.

Comment: Can be just as easily done wtih `grep -oP 'some perl regex' file.txt | wc -l`

Comment: But really just google `awk count lines`, `awk regex`, or something, and you should get there. It's unlikely you'll get a direct answer to a homework problem here.

Comment: BroSlow I've breezed through my other questions with no problems, but the wording of this question has thrown me off tremendously and I'm unable to find a solution that works so far. I've used my textbook and the internet as my guides.

Comment: @RobertPlant You should check for the line start character, then check that's followed by `(`, then that that's followed by 1+ decimal characters, i.e. `\d+` or `[0-9]+` or some such construct, then followed by a closing `)`. After that the directions are not very clear, and if possible I would have your teacher confirm. If not, I would assume that the sentence can include regular parts like upper/lower case letters, `,` , `.` (since it's included in example), `;`, `:`, `'`, space, etc... And explain in your solution what you include/exlude. Then make sure it's terminated by `.$`

Comment: @RobertPlant If I were reading the directions verbatim, I would assume it should only be `^\([0-9]+\)(UPPER|LOWER)*\.$` (this isn't real regex, but pretty close to what you would want), and maybe even require that it has at least one upper and one lower. But again directions are not very clear, so if you can't ask, I would make a best guess based on examples and include an explanation of that guess along with solution.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.

Comment: @RobertPlant Also, depending on whether the decimal number can start with a `0`, may want to check that it's explicitly `0` or [1-9], followed by 0 or more [0-9].

Answer (score 1):

This is not a homework solution service. But I think I can give a few pointers.

One idea would be to create a counter, and then print the result at the end:

```
awk '<COND> {c++} END {print c}'
```

I'm getting a bit confused by the terminology. First you claim that the lines should be counted, but in the examples, it says that those lines should be printed.

Now of course you could do something like this:

```
awk '<COND>' file.txt | wc -l
```

The first part will print out all lines that follow the condition, but the output will be parsed to `wc -l` which is a separate program that counts the number of lines.

Now as to what the condition `<COND>` should be, I leave to you. I strongly suggest that you google regular expressions and awk, it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: chw21, I don't use StackOverflow as a homework service, but I am also getting confused by some of the exact wording in this question and since it is only 1 line, I really thought I should turn to the minds of the internet for this question specifically. I don't know how to break it down any simpler than this. Thank you for your response!

Comment: But again, the question is copied word for word. I didn't put this question into my own words. What you see here is what I was given.

Answer (score 0):

I think the requirement is very clear

> Write a one line shell command that will count all lines in a file called "file.txt" that begin with a decimal number in parenthesis, containing a mix of both upper and lower case letters, and end with a period.

```
1. begin with a decimal number in parenthesis
2. containing a mix of both upper and lower case letters
3. end with a period
```

check all three conditions.  Note that in 2. it doesn't say "only" so you can have extra class of characters but it should have at least one uppercase and one lowercase character.

The example mixes concepts printing and counting, if part of the exercise it's very poorly worded or perhaps assumes that the counting will be done by `wc` by a piped output of a filtering script; regardless more attention should have been paid, especially for a student exercise.

Please comment if anything not clear and I'll add more details...